# seach in google via firefox's address bar - keyworld:URL does not exist

Tags: firefox, search-engine, keyword, address-bar

I'm used to search in google by typing keywords to my address bar. Now for some reason every word I'm typing is tried to interprete as a website. It is similar to google's "I'm feeling lucky" option, but with the difference that I can only type one word and only if it is writte correctly. Typing `stackoverflow` directed me to `stackoverflow.com` but `rtackoverflow` led to an error page.

In older versions we would enter about:config and change the value of keyword.URL.

I've already read that keyword.URL has no functionality anymore but this can be undone by installing FireFox - Addons like keyword.URL-HACK.
That did not work, because I don't have any keyword.URL in about:config!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this firefox addon: [InstantFox Quick Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/)

**[InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/)** combines the Firefox address bar with the search box.

Here is it's introductory video: http://y2u.be/W-BvOGf0kaM

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Add-on [Keyword.URL Hack!](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/keywordurl-hack/)
2. Enter about:config in the address bar and click the button
3. type `keyword.URL` in the search
4. if it does not exists, creat it: right click and select new->string
5. enter keyword.URL as the key and `http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=` as the value (or what ever search engine you like)
6. search for `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` and set its value to `false`

Comment: This addon has been removed from addons.mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any addon for this.

You can turn on the web search in the address bar by changing a preference.
(Note: This preference does not affect smart keyword searches from the Location Bar)

1. In the address bar, type `about:config` and press Enter.

   - The `about:config` warning page (This might void your warranty!) may appear. Click I accept the risk! to continue to the about:config page.
2. In the Search field, type keyword.enabled.
3. Double-click the `keyword.enabled` preference to set its value to `true`.

By the way, the default value of `keyword.enabled` is `true` but I had accidentally changed it to `false`.

More details [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar)